# Utilização do JTable

Tags: java, swing, eclipse, netbeans, jtable

Sou novo no assunto e por tanto já estou fazendo alguns cursos na área, mas enquanto não fico bom, estou tendo muitas duvidas.

Primeiramente desculpa não postar uma parte do código, mas a empresa que trabalho é tudo bloqueado e estou fazendo essa pergunta do meu computador pessoal em casa...

Mas vamos lá, espero ser claro na dúvida.

Preciso saber se é possível setar uma linha no JTable.

Ex: Na linha vai estar marcando a sua informação Comida (Arroz).

Dúvida: Eu consigo pegar essa informação do JTable e ao iniciar o programa já venha com a linha selecionada?

[image: Imagem simples de exemplo]

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Edi.
Acho que a pergunta não ficou muito clara, talvez por conta disso tenha tido poucas respostas. Vou tentar te ajudar com o que eu entendi, qualquer dúvida, fique à vontade para comentar que eu tento adequar a resposta a sua necessidade.
Sobre a parte "Preciso saber se é possível setar uma linha no JTable.". Sim, é possível.
Sobre a dúvida "Eu consigo pegar essa informação do JTable e ao iniciar o programa já venha com a linha selecionada?", a resposta é: sim, porém algumas coisas precisarão ser preparadas para isso.

Pelo que estou entendendo, você terá uma tabela onde as comidas não se repetirão, sendo assim, uma vez que a linha da comida "Arroz" seja selecionada, você deseja iniciar o programa da próxima vez com a linha arroz marcada como antes.
Para guardar essa informação você precisará armazená-la em algum lugar, podendo ser um [arquivo de propriedades](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) ou em um banco de dados. Opte por utilizar o mesmo armazenamento que você já utiliza para guardar os seus dados.
A única informação que você precisará guardar é a comida, como você descreveu, porém, uma sugestão minha é que você utilize o ID, pois teoricamente o ID não se repetirá, já a comida, poderia se repetir.
Armazenando essa informação, busque-a quando iniciar o programa e utilize alguma forma para realizar a busca na tabela. Assim que você encontrar a linha desejada, utilize o metodo *suatabela.setRowSelectionInterval( i, i );* para determinar a linha a ser selecionada. A variável *suatabela* deve conter o mesmo nome que você criou para a tabela e o *i* é a linha que você resgatou ao fazer a busca.
Caso possua alguma dúvida com essa resposta, ou queira acrescentar alguma informação, fique à vontade para comentar.
Abraços e Boa sorte.